# How to add links to a cell note in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We can just add text to a cell notes but looking for a way to add links to it

Although we can add links as a multiple comments over the cell but haven't found any solution to add in notes

Answer (score 2):

Google Sheets notes only supports plain text (string).

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNote(String)